# Yii: from a view, how do I found out where a variable came from?

Tags: php, yii

In a Yii project passed to me, there's a function that creates (or shows?) a textbox when the button/link `Comment` is clicked. From there, the user can create Comments, which will be displayed in a row.

I'm trying to see if I can create an edit comment function, so I thought I could go about this by copying the Comment function - it'll show a textbox, and the user can input the new text in there. And instead of adding a new comment, it will edit the existing one.

But I hit a snag, as apparently the `view.php` makes use of a variable that I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to use in `_comments.php` - the file responsible for displaying the individual comments, afaik.

Here's the code for `view.php`:

```
</script>

<?php
$this->breadcrumbs=array('Forums'=>array('index'),$model->title,);
?>
<?php 
    if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('message')):
        echo '<script>alert("'.Yii::app()->user->getFlash('message').'");</script>'; 
    endif;
?>

<?php $starter = Persons::model()->findByAttributes(array('party_id'=>$model->party_id));?>
<div id="forum_main_box">
    <div class="comment-icon-textbox">
        <?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Comment',array('forum/callcommentform'),
              array(
                'update' => '#render_div'.$model->id,
                'data'=>array('id'=>$model->id),
              )); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div id="forum_comment_headerbox">
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',
                array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                    'itemView'=>'_comments',
                    'summaryText'=>'',
                )); 
        ?>
        <div id="render_div<?=$model->id?>" class="comment-form">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of that code, below is the `Comment` link I spoke of:

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Comment',array('forum/callcommentform'),
    array(
        'update' => '#render_div'.$model->id,
        'data'=>array('id'=>$model->id),
    )); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This block displays the list of comments, and what (I assume to be) the space where the textbox will pop up when the above `Comment` is clicked:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',
    array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_comments',
        'summaryText'=>'',
    )); 
?>
<div id="render_div<?=$model->id?>" class="comment-form">
</div>
```

Notice that both makes use of `$model`. It first appeared in the code as `$model->title`.

And here's a shortened version of the `_comments.php`, which is used for the comment rows and the comment box.

```
<?php $comment = $data; ?>
<div class="other-member-comment-box">
    <?php $person=Persons::model()->findByAttributes(array('party_id'=>$comment->party_id)); ?>
    <?php 
        $country=Lookup_codes::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$person->country)); 
        $location = empty($country) ? '' : ' - '.$country->name;
        // $model->title;
    ?>
    <?php if (Yii::app()->user->id == $person->party_id || Yii::app()->partyroles->isAdmin()) { 
    ?>
    <p class="admin-commands">
        <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode('Edit'),array('forum/editcomment','reply'=>$data->id,'topic'=>$data->content_id)); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('EditTestComment',array('forum/callcommentform'),array('update' => '#render_div'.$model->id,'data'=>array('id'=>$model->content_id),)); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode('Delete'),array('forum/delete','reply'=>$data->id,'topic'=>$data->content_id),array('confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')); ?>
        <div id="render_div<?=$model->id?>" class="comment-form">

        </div>
    </p>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Under `<p class="admin-commands">`, there's a `EditTestComment` link which is a straight up copy of the `Comment` code from the `view.php`. This doesn't work, of course, because of this:

> 2016/04/07 10:24:03 [error] [php] Undefined variable: model

Where'd `$model` come from in `view.php`? Because putting in the same line ($model->title) anywhere in `_comments.php` just breaks it further.

EDIT: Here's the CallComment part of the controller:

```
public function actionCallCommentForm($id='')
{
    $topic=Forum::model()->findByPk($id);
    $this->renderPartial('_commentform', array(
        'forum'=>$topic,
        'model'=>new Comment,
        //'view'=>array('view','id'=>$id),
        'view'=>'view',
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$model variable is coming from your controller initially. It is an instance of a Comment class which gets passed to the view via `$this->render('view', array('model'=>$whatever))`. This line will make $whatever available in the forum/view.php file under the name of $model. Now since you are dealing with partial views you have to track it because it is possible that the same $model variable will be passed to another partial view with `$this->renderPartial('_comment', array('whatever'=>$model))` and now this will be accessible in partial view as $whatever.

Comment: I've added the `actionCallCommentForm`, which is what's called when the user clicks on Comment. There's a model there that's being passed, but the error remains the same, on the .php files.

Comment: if it displays that msg than you are not passing it correctly. You can var_dump model and see what you get. If there is nothing dump it in the view before. Track it back to the controller.

Comment: Log / Dump it from `actionView`? I also tried `renderInternal`, didn't work.

Comment: Okay, in your widget you are specifying itemView as _comments and your actual file is called _comment.php that could be the source of the problem. Also I'm not sure if you in your controller are sending `$model` to the _commentform.php intentionally and if you have that file at all. Thirdly I'm not sure what should the last line in the render partial represent 'view' => 'view'. If you want to send it to the view than that is the first argument of render method. You just need to send `$model` to _comment.php.

Comment: Sorry about that, I typed it wrong up there, it was actually _comments.php. There is a _commentform.php, but I haven't paid attention to that yet, as the sending of `$model` is my main issue - don't really know how / where (in ForumController.php?) to do that.